# XSL Reversing the order with a counter

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have a very unusual scenario. Never heard or done something like this before. Here's my source XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListItems>
   <List>
     <name>A</name>
   </List>
   <List>
     <name>B</name>
   </List>
   <List>
     <name>C</name>
   </List>
   <List>
     <name>D</name>
   </List>
</ListItems>
```

What I am looking to do is to reverse the order of the list with a reverse counter added as an index. The resultant XML should look like this:

```
<UpdateListItems>
   <List>
     <name>D</name>
     <index>4</index>
   </List>
   <List>
     <name>C</name>
     <index>3</index>
   </List>
   <List>
     <name>B</name>
     <index>2</index>
   </List>
   <List>
     <name>A</name>
     <index>1</index>
   </List>
</UpdateListItems>
```

Notice the names in reverse order with an index added in reverse order. Sounds a bit stupid but is it possible to do this in xml transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes its possible. Use the <xsl:sort> element with attribute order="descending" when apply templates  to List element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0" >
    <xsl:output method = "xml" />

    <xsl:template match = "/ListItems" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "List" >
                <xsl:sort order="descending" select="position()" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "node()|@*" >
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select = "node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match = "List" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "name"/>
            <index><xsl:value-of select="1 + last() - position()"/></index>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Edited: I forgot to include the select="position()" data-type="number" attributes in sort element

Edited again to answer your additional requirements: 
Replaced (as already pointed out by Daniel)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select = "node()|@*"/>
```

by this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select = "name"/>
```

Or if you prefer you can use this. Notice the last empty template which suppress any List's child except the the child name

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0" >
    <xsl:output method = "xml" />

    <xsl:template match = "/ListItems" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "List" >
                <xsl:sort order="descending" select="position()" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "node()|@*" >
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select = "node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match = "List" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "node()|@*"/>
            <index><xsl:value-of select="1 + last() - position()"/></index>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="List/*[not(self::name)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1, although as you've marked your post as "community wiki" you won't get any reputation benefit from this.  If you clicked the checkbox by mistake, flag your post and ask a moderator to revert it.

Comment: @Ian Roberts
Thanks for your advice. I was not aware of that. I am new here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly the result I was looking for. Can you please explain how the whole thing works. I noticed that you have not used for-each. The copy is doing the trick. How the index working? Thanks

Comment: @RKS I always avoid for-each as it implies a more imperative programing style. The xsl is essential a declarative programing language and I prefer to use that model. 
The xsl:copy copies the matched element.

Comment: @RKS - You can also replace the entire `<xsl:value-of select="1 + last() - position()"/>` with `<xsl:number/>`.

Comment: @jvverde - I noticed that your approach may not work if there another element underneath <name>.

Comment: @jvverde - If the input xml is like this:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListItems>
   <List>
     <name>A</name>
     <name1>AA</name1>
   </List>
   <List>
     <name>B</name>
     <name1>BB</name1>
   </List>
   <List>
     <name>C</name>
     <name1>CC</name1>
   </List>
   <List>
     <name>D</name>
     <name1>DD</name1>
   </List>
</ListItems>

Comment: @jvverde - When I run the transformation it's returning me this:   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ListItems><List>
     <name>D</name>
     <name1>DD</name1>
   <index>4</index></List><List>
     <name>C</name>
     <name1>CC</name1>
   <index>3</index></List><List>
     <name>B</name>
     <name1>BB</name1>
   <index>2</index></List><List>
     <name>A</name>
     <name1>AA</name1>
   <index>1</index></List></ListItems>

Comment: @jvverde - Notice the additional <name1>DD</name1>. Where as if I only want name and index elements then how do you do it?

Comment: @Daniel - <xsl:number/> doesn't seem to work. It always returns 1 in this case.

Comment: @RKS - In the template for `List`, change `node()` in the `xsl:apply-templates` to `name`. Also, with the input you've supplied, the `xsl:number` works for me with both Saxon and Xalan. If you're interested, take a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number for more info on `xsl:number`.

Comment: @RKS, The solution is a very generic one and, of course, depends on your XML source structure. If you have more elements and wants to suppress them just follow the Daniel suggestion above or add an empty template for others List's child. <xsl:template match="List/*[not(self::name)]"/>

Comment: The xsl:number is a valid alternative. It works with xalan and xsltproc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Daniel and jwerde. Got Daniel suggestion working but not yet sure of <xsl:template match="List/*[not(self::name)]"/>. Yet to figure out the xsl:number, going to have a look at your link.

Comment: So for xsl:number I need to put like this <xsl:number value="1 + last() - position()" format="1. "/>. It works but now it's more or less like xsl:value-of select

Comment: The xsl:number without arguments is supposed to give you the original List position in source code. Of course if need to use value and format arguments the xsl:value-of alternative is shorter

Comment: @jwerde - thanks. Can you explain a little more about <xsl:template match="List/*[not(self::name)]"/>

Comment: @RKS the xpath expression List/* gives you a set with all element child of List. If you use a predicate (square bracket) you remove from that set all nodes for which expression in false. In this case you are removing only the element which name is __name__. So you end up with all children of list except the element __name__. And then you substitute those elements for the content of template which is empty. So you replace those element by nothing.

Comment: thanks for the `1 + last() - position()` - exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

In your xsl you can sort the List in descending order based on position.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
<xsl:template match="/">
<UpdatedListItems>
<xsl:for-each select="/ListItems/List/name">
<xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
<List>
<name><xsl:value-of select="."/></name>
</List>
</xsl:for-each>
</UpdatedListItems>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Running this through xsltproc on your corrected input (change `<name/> to </name>`) produces the following result:

> `<UpdatedListItems><List><name>D</name></List><List><name>C</name></List><List><name>B</name></List><List><name>A</name></List></UpdatedListItems>`

Comment: Sorry about the input. I noticed the closing tag after the post.